# Issue with multiple Synchronous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to fire synchronous ajax calls consecutively.

After each call I'm updating a *DOM element*.

Now this is where the issue occurs,the element gets updated only when all the calls are finished.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "analysis.py?id="+id, false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Done id "+id;
id+=10;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "analysis.py?id="+id, false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = document.getElementById("res").innerHTML+"Done id "+id;
```

The element dom shows : `Done id 1Done id 11` all at once instead of one after another as was expected i.e. The element is directly updated at the end of both calls.

Edit 1:
Hi guys, 
Just found another issue with my code. The following code runs only the first ajax, after that the ajax calls seem to run but the work defined in analysis.py is not done for these calls.

```
var total = %d;
    function filldatabase(){
    var id = 1;
    callajax(id);
}
function callajax(id){
    $.ajax({
          url: "analysis.py?id="+id,
          context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
          $("#progress").html(Math.floor(((id/(total-5))*100))+"%%");
          $("#pbar").css("width", ((id/(total-5))*100) + "%%");
          if(id<=1296){
                callajax(id+10);
          }
          else{
            $("#res").html("Completed. Redirecting in 5 seconds...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=get_comment.py'>");
          }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do it synchronously?

Comment: Actually I need to update progress after each 10 processed id's. Since I'm using Python through CGI scripts. I've no clue on any other method for the same.

Comment: You need to call them as callbacks on one another. Javascript does not execute in sequential order with async calls. E.g. it doesn't natively wait for an async call to complete.

Comment: Your stuff is going so fast that its not making a difference. Anyways, you can do it asynchronously using callbacks. The simplest way to do that use to use a library like jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. Solved it by using jquery callbacks

Comment: @mason There's a new issue if you could help with that.

Comment: @NickM There's a new issue if you could help with that

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by calling the next ajax in the previous one's callback.